# Creating back end for iOS application

Tags: .net, back

I am looking into different options for creating backend for my iOS application.

.NET: I am using Mac for development and pararrels is super slow to develop for .NET

Ruby on Rails: Pain to install and lots of problems with Mavericks

PHP: Should I use PHP??

NodeJS: Not many resources dealing with SQLIte databases

Other options?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends too much on what you're trying to do. Since I don't really know much about your application, I'll tell you what I've used.

I use PHP and MySQL on the backend for my iOS projects. I have an app in the App Store that manages user data and has been running strong for several years with active traffic.

I used the open source library [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) (though I think now there is a more popular library being used) on the client to communicate to my server that is hosting my PHP files.

To give you an idea of how simple it is to get started with:

iOS code to communicate with php backend

```
-(void)login
{
    NSString * link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver.com/login.php", sourceLink];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setPostValue:username forKey:@"username"];
    [request setPostValue:password forKey:@"password"];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Php code to receive the credentials to log in the user

```
<?php
    $username           = $_POST['username'];
    $password           = $_POST['password'];

    // Do stuff with the username and password
?>
```

Of course there is sanitation / validation / security / etc that must be done, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs is great for developing APIs. The nodejs standard modules are quite straightforward, the environment is fast and it is a technology that is growing fast in adoption. It has a great package management system (npm) that lets you focus on your app and not dealing with dependency hell.

I would recommend you to use expressjs as web framework. It is really simple to do a REST API with express. Basically:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    doDatabaseSearch(function(err, result) {
        if (err) return res.json(500, {error:'Internal error'})
        res.json(result)
    })
})
```

On the other hand you could use a mobile backend-as-a-service such as [Backbeam](https://backbeam.io), parse.com, kinvey, etc. so you can focus on your app instead of wasting time on the backend stuff.

In the iOS part I recommend you to use [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) as HTTP library. Or if you are using a third-party backend you should use its SDK such as the Backbeam's one: [iOS SDK](http://backbeam.io/documentation-ios).